# IllegalArgumentException after form submission returns message

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a UIPanel that contains form elements.  On click of submit, the form validates all the fields and if they are all valid, proceeds to insert the field values into the DB.  If the DB returns a duplicate key exception, I show a message telling the user to update the field (See http://goo.gl/jOzZGG).

The message shows up, and the form loads properly for the most part, but a problem occurs when the Calendar element throws

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
```

If I submit the form and the forms finds errors during validation (related or unrelated to this Calendar field) there are no problems, only after validation is completed, and I add this message does it throw this exception.

Code for how I am generating the Calendar is below, but I am not sure why it would only throw an error in this scenario and not any other.

```
Calendar input = new Calendar();
input.setPattern("MM/dd/yyy");
input.setId(inputId);
input.setStyleClass(inputId);
input.setShowOn("button");
input.setNavigator(true);
input.setValueBinding("value", vb);
if(defaultVal != null && !defaultVal.equals("")){   
    SimpleDateFormat dbFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    String defaultDate = displayFormat.format(dbFormat.parse(defaultVal));
    Date date = new Date();
    date = displayFormat.parse(defaultDate);                            
    if(required != null && !required.equals("") && !required.equals(",") && mandatory.length > 1){
        if(mandatory[1].equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
            input.setRequired(true);
            input.setRequiredMessage("Please enter a  "+inputLabel+".");
            HtmlMessage message = new HtmlMessage();
            message.setFor(inputId);
            message.setStyleClass("errorMessage");
            div.getChildren().add(input);
            div.getChildren().add(message);
        }else{
            input.setRequired(false);
            div.getChildren().add(input);
        }
    }else{
        div.getChildren().add(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it safe the assume the error points to the line: String defaultDate = displayFormat.format(dbFormat.parse(defaultVal))? How's defaultVal declared and assigned?  See what value it has before this line when the error occurs.

Comment: No, this actually compiles fine.  I have some logs which I removed for the post, and everything compiles fine, goes all the way to the end of the method.... the error comes when the page tries to render.  defaultVal is a string declared earlier on the page.

Comment: The console displays this error:

`SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/common/copy.xhtml]`
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date`